# What's the difference between CRUD and CRUDL?

Tags: database, function, pagination, crud

I don't understand the difference between `read` and `list`. According to Wikipedia:

> The acronym may be extended to CRUDL to cover listing of large data
>   sets which bring additional complexity such as pagination when the
>   data sets are too large to hold easily in memory

The way i see this is just a read, and if you decide to support pagination, your result will be paginated. **It doesnt fundamentally change the way in which someone interacts with the system**. You are fundamentally returning data i.e. `read`. And what if you want to paginate `read` results? Does that then make it a list?

Im currently on a project where we are being ask to support both a list and a read, and other than the pagination, I'm struggling to see any implementation differences.

Are there other reasons you should separate `read` and `list` into their own functions

Comment: "We are being asked to support both a list and a read": If it's not absolutely clear what your client wants, you should try to get more details. Providing something which meets your client's needs is more important than following the Wikipedia definition of "R" and "L".

Comment: I absolutely agree. I'm not directly involved in this part of the project, someone asked my opinion, and thought I would check with the experts if there was something I was missing

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have never seen a definitive definition of what "list" means in a CRUD context, but I have implemented quite a few systems that uses a CRUD approach. Here's some items you might consider for separating "list" operations from "read" operations:

- Additional searching/filtering parameters (while "read" typically returns one or all items of a kind)
- List methods may return "shallow" objects for faster access (where objects from "read" methods are large/expensive)
- Pagination (as you already mention)
- Some might even consider all methods returning multiple objects "list" operations (where "read" operations return only one item)

But I have to agree with you. None of these *fundamentally change* the way you interact with the system. It's basically still reading data, perhaps just a little smarter.

Comment: To expand on the above and attempt to put a label on it, a list is seems more of a directory feature, as opposed to returning the 'actual data', (as correctly) suggested above. Whilst they are both technically `read`, there is a big difference between doing a google search and getting 1 million links and summaries loaded 20 results at a time, and getting all million pages delivered at once.

Comment: The 2nd item also considers security reasons, e.g a RO role on data bucket can access a collection of shallow objects but it requests granular permission to access the spec with (larger) details.

Answer (score 18):

For simplicity:

- `READ` gets an object.
- `LIST` queries a list of IDs for which you can later `READ` the underlying object or not.

## Social network web example

For example, say you operate a social network website.

Imagine that and each `User` object is like 10 or 20kB long, as you have there tons of things (lists of friends, last searches, albums and photos listings, cookies, last visited pages, list of posts, list of likes, etc).

Imagine also that you have a route and `controller` that shows a user's profile getting data from the `model` and injecting it into a `view`. Let's call it the `profile-page-view`.

It is obvious that the `controller` must get all the data in order to pass it to the view renderer.

Imagine that in the `profile-page-view` you have a `friends-widget` showing the user's 100-most active friends, and imagine too that you're gonna use all that information (cannot query a partial set of info) to display in each specific `user-miniwidget` links, posts, photos, etc.

Instead of getting 100 users at a time, which is 10k x 100 users = 1MB of information retrieved from the database, you may opt just to `LIST` the profiles's most active friends, getting the IDs and not the objects.

And then have the controller to `READ` only the first 5 of the list (50kB of handled info) spitting them to the HTML.

Then read the other 95 via a sequence of AJAX calls... for example:

- the users 11 to 50 queried in blocks of 5, triggering the first "5 object-`READ` operations" 2 seconds after the page load, and each subsequent block 1 second after the previous one has returned, up to user 50 in the list.
- the remaining ones (50 to 100) only triggered if the browser scrolls to that area or the mouse moves near by.

This is an example where `LIST` and `READ` are completely separated.

## Model API example

Imagine the API of a model of a system to help companies to sell more. This calculates a set of data over products.

An invoice has lines, and each line has a product associated.

To get the product of the 3rd line of the invoice 4444 you could do:

```
// Pseudo-language.

InvoiceManager invoiceManager;
Invoice invoice;
InvoiceLine line;
Product product;

invoiceManager = whateverDependencyInjectionSystemYouUse.getService( "InvoiceManager" );
invoice = invoiceManager.getInvoiceById( 4444 );
line = invoice.lines[ 3 ];
product = line.getProduct();
```

This performs a READ operation on the product. If it is lazy-loaded, the `READ` is performed on the `line.getProduct();` line of code.

Nevertheless if you want to see the top-sellers of a certain product family, maybe you do not need to "load" all the products in RAM.

Say you want to display the details of the 20 top-selling of the product category "Flowers":

```
// Pseudo-language.

ProductManager productManager;
ProductFamily productFamily;
Products products;
Product product;

productManager = whateverDependencyInjectionSystemYouUse.getService( "ProductManager" );
productFamily = productManager.getProductFamilyByName( "Flowers" );
products = productFamilies.getAllProductsSortedByAmountSoldLastMonth()

max = 20;
ctr = 0;
foreach( product in products )
{
    dump( p );

    ctr++;
    if( ctr >= max )
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

In this case, the `productFamily.getAllProductsSortedByAmountSoldLastMonth()` method would implement a `LIST` reading at most, but no way would load the real objects inside. **What if that category had 1 million flower products in it?!?!?! - That would be a suicide!**

Then each iteration on the `products.getItem()` -implicit call in each iteration of the for-each loop-, the real `READ` would be performed to query the real object.

## In short

Normally in `LIST` you get IDs you can manage and store super easily in a lightweight manner to later `READ` the objects behind or not.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

- `READ` returns a single item
- `LIST` returns an array of items